# Como verificar se o cpf e o cnpj ja existem no banco de dados (Pdo Php)

Tags: php, pdo

Eu estou tentando fazer uma verificação quando quero cadastrar um cliente. Antes de cadastrar quero verificar se o cpf ou o cnpj do cliente já existe no banco de dados. quando tento verificar somente o cpf ele funciona e retorna um alerte e quando tento verificar somente o cnpj, também ele da certo, mas quando tento fazer para os dois, ele me retorna um erro dizendo que o cliente já existe enquanto esse dado informado não se-encontra no banco.

Aqui está o que fiz

```
 //CHECKING IF THERE IS ALREADY A CNPJ OR CPF REGISTERED
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from rcom_clientes_clientes WHERE cnpj= ? OR cpf=?");
    $stmt -> bindValue(1 ,$cnpj);
    $stmt -> bindValue(2 ,$cpf);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $count = $stmt->rowcount();


//IF THE CLIENT ALREADY EXIST
if( $count > 0 )
{
  echo"<script>alert('Desculpa, esse Cliente ja 
   existe!');window.location.href = '../../create_client.php';</script>";  

}
else
{
   ECHO 'DEU';
}
```

Alguém pode me dar uma mão ai?

Comment: Se $cpf estiver vazio e $cnpj estiver preenchido com um número que não exista no banco, retornará resultados o qual o $cpf esteja vazio no banco de dados. Exemplo: $cpf = '' e $cnpj = '001': Se não existir o '001' no banco, ainda assim retornará todos os registros que 'cpf' esteja vazio. O mais correto seria verificar no PHP qual a variável que foi preenchida ($cnpj ou $cpf) e então fazer uma query apenas da variável preenchida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras de se fazer isso, uma delas é você criar uma função para validar qualquer campo, com essa função "genérica" você pode aproveitar para validar qualquer campo único como por exemplo: email, username e etc.

```
/**
 * Função para verificar se já existe um cadastro no banco de dados
 * a partir de um campo único.
 *
 */
public function validarCampoUnico(string $field, string $value)
{
    $allowedFIelds = ['cpf', 'cnpj'];
    if (!in_array($field, $allowedFIelds)) {
        // Lançar exception ou tratar o erro da forma que você já trata seus erros da aplicação
    }

    // Caso os valores sejam armazenados no banco sem mascara
    // Isso vai remover a mascara do valor antes de enviar para o banco
    $value = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $value);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from rcom_clientes_clientes WHERE {$field} = ?");
    $stmt->bindValue(1 ,$value);
    $stmt->execute(); 

    if ($stmt->rowcount() <= 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


// Como você não informou a maneira que estava recebendo os dados,
// estou apenas dando um exemplo de utilização.
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];

if (validarCampoUnico('cpf', $cpf)) {
    echo"<script>alert('Desculpa, esse Cliente ja 
   existe!');window.location.href = '../../create_client.php';</script>"; 
} else {
    echo 'Deu';
}
```